# MongoDB Query - Count Objects/Arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need some help with the following query in Mongo. I am trying to count how many items are False
I have an object called "comments" inside I have arrays with the departments ("Paint", "Metal, "Assembly"....) and within the departments, I have objects. I need to count when "read"=false.

[image]

Comment: Please try to post text content instead of screenshots, and show where you failed in your attempts.

Comment: "trying to count how many items are False" ... in the entire collection? ... per document? ... per array?

Comment: In the "comments" object

Comment: in the entire collection

Comment: So, you want **one single number** which represents the total number of `"read": false` for the entire collection?

Comment: I haven't completely understood exactly what is wanted here, but in case it's the number of `"read": false` per document, here's a [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zbDsuYNHmne "Click me!").  The `mgodatagen` configuration might be useful for other queries.

Comment: It might help if you post a sample expected result document.